# How can i gather threads number per process and find the max in bash terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, process

I want to gather how many threads does a process use (from their PID/status i guess) and after that i wanna compare them and output the biggest number of them. For example i wanna gather all threads per chromium's processes and then compare the numbers and output the max. Any ideas?

E.g

2131 Threads : 20 , 2341 Threads : 10 , 2200 Threads : 5

Max Threads = 20

Answer (score 0):

in ubuntu you can get no of thread for process using this command

```
ps -o nlwp `pgrep process_name`
```

nlwp stands for number of light weight process